# Lua cURL POST Invalid Json [Pusher API]

Tags: json, curl, lua, pusher

I am attempting to use cURL with the Pusher API (pusher.com). However I keep getting the response "Invalid JSON provided (could not parse)". Any help would be appreciated, here is my trigger function:

```
function trigger(name, data, channel)
    string_to_sign = "POST\n/apps/"..pusher_app_id.."/events\n"..params
    signature = hmac.digest("sha256", string_to_sign, pusher_secret)

    md5 = md5.sumhexa('{"name":"foo","channel":"test-channel","data":"{\"some\":\"data\"}"}');

    c = curl.new()
    c:setopt(curl.OPT_URL, pusher_server..'apps/'..pusher_app_id..'/events'..'?'..params..'&auth_signature='..signature..'&body_md5='..md5)
    c:setopt(curl.OPT_POST, true)
    c:setopt(curl.OPT_HTTPHEADER, "Content-Type: application/json")
    c:setopt(curl.OPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"name":"'..name..'","channel":"'..channel..'","data":"{\"some\":\"data\"}"}')
    c:perform()
    c:close()
end
```

If I print the JSON I am putting in OPT_POSTFIELDS and paste it into a json validator, it is indeed completely valid. According to the docs this is the proper usage for /events and my authentication is also working fine.

Comment: You hashing different value then send. PS. I found that creating easy handle for each new rquest is quite expensive operation. So may be you can reuse same handle?

Comment: On what line (mark it) is that error raised?

Comment: The error is the response from pusher and not on any particular line. The JSON in postfields is an issue somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I had gone back through my function applying the suggestions moteus commented and was able to resolve my problem by fixing the md5 and applying it to the signature. I am also using the luajson module to take care of encoding. This seemed to fix the issue.

```
function trigger(name, data, channel)
  data_table = {
    ["name"] = name,
    ["channel"] = channel,
    ["data"] = data
  }

  json_data = json.encode(data_table)
  md5 = md5.sumhexa(json_data)

  string_to_sign = "POST\n/apps/"..pusher_app_id.."/events\n"..params.."&body_md5="..md5
  signature = hmac.digest("sha256", string_to_sign, pusher_secret)

  c:setopt(curl.OPT_URL, pusher_server..'apps/'..pusher_app_id..'/events'..'?'..params..'&auth_signature='..signature..'&body_md5='..md5)
  c:setopt(curl.OPT_POST, true)
  c:setopt(curl.OPT_HTTPHEADER, "Content-Type: application/json")
  c:setopt(curl.OPT_POSTFIELDS, json_data)
  c:perform()
  c:close()
end
```